# Java library that finds sentence boundaries

Tags: java, string, nlp, text-segmentation

Does anyone know of a Java library that handles finding sentence boundaries? I'm thinking that it would be a smart StringTokenizer implementation that knows about all of the sentence terminators that languages can use.

Here's my experience with BreakIterator:

Using the example [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/i18n/text/examples/BreakIteratorDemo.java):
I have the following Japanese:

```
今日はパソコンを買った。高性能のマックは早い！とても快適です。
```

In ascii, it looks like this:

```
\ufeff\u4eca\u65e5\u306f\u30d1\u30bd\u30b3\u30f3\u3092\u8cb7\u3063\u305f\u3002\u9ad8\u6027\u80fd\u306e\u30de\u30c3\u30af\u306f\u65e9\u3044\uff01\u3068\u3066\u3082\u5feb\u9069\u3067\u3059\u3002
```

Here's the part of that sample that I changed:
  static void sentenceExamples() {

```
  Locale currentLocale = new Locale ("ja","JP");
  BreakIterator sentenceIterator = 
     BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance(currentLocale);
  String someText = "今日はパソコンを買った。高性能のマックは早い！とても快適です。";
```

When I look at the Boundary indices, I see this:

```
0|13|24|32
```

But those indices don't correspond to any sentence terminators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote:

> I'm thinking that it would be a smart StringTokenizer implementation that knows about all of the sentence terminators that languages can use.

A basic problem here is that sentence terminators depend on the context, consider:

> How did Dr. Jones compute 5! without recursion?

This should be recognized as a single sentence, but if you just split on possible sentence terminators you will get three sentences.

So this is a more complex problem than one might think in the beginning. It can be approached using machine learning techniques. You could for instance look into the [OpenNLP](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/) project, in particular the [SentenceDetectorME](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/api/opennlp/tools/sentdetect/SentenceDetectorME.html) class.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I understand why there isn't a library that does what I need. Cheers!

Comment: The library that I linked to in my answer handles that example.

Comment: Bill, yes I tried it too, cool. Won't work for Japanese, though.

Answer (score 4):

You want to look into the internationalized BreakIterator classes. A good starting point for [sentence boundaries](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/i18n/text/sentence.html).

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working with my Japanese test. I tried it with both Japanese characters and ascii characters (converted using native2ascii)

Comment: @Mike - what sentence terminator are you testing? Cursory testing with \u3002 worked for me.